# PyQt4 center window on active screen

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

How I can center window on active screen but not on general screen? This code moves window to center on general screen, not active screen:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.resize(640, 480)
        self.setWindowTitle('Backlight management')
        self.center()

        self.show()

    def center(self):
        frameGm = self.frameGeometry()
        centerPoint = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        frameGm.moveCenter(centerPoint)
        self.move(frameGm.topLeft())

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I removes **self.center()** from **initUI()** then window opened on 0x0 on active screen. I need to open window on active screen and move this window on center of this screen. Thansk!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Modify your `center` method to be as follows:

```
def center(self):
    frameGm = self.frameGeometry()
    screen = QtGui.QApplication.desktop().screenNumber(QtGui.QApplication.desktop().cursor().pos())
    centerPoint = QtGui.QApplication.desktop().screenGeometry(screen).center()
    frameGm.moveCenter(centerPoint)
    self.move(frameGm.topLeft())
```

This function is based on where the mouse point is located. It uses the [screenNumber](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdesktopwidget.html#screenNumber-2) function to determine which screen the mouse is current active on. It then finds the [screenGeometry](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdesktopwidget.html#screenGeometry) of that monitor and the center point of that screen. Using this method, you should be able to place the window in the center of a screen even if monitor resolutions are different.

Comment: Note this didn't centre the screen properly for me without the call to `resize()` first

Answer (score 9):

One correction for PyQt5 users:

```
import PyQt5

def center(self):
    frameGm = self.frameGeometry()
    screen = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().screenNumber(PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().cursor().pos())
    centerPoint = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().screenGeometry(screen).center()
    frameGm.moveCenter(centerPoint)
    self.move(frameGm.topLeft())
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another (late) answer:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDesktopWidget

def center(self):
    qr = self.frameGeometry()
    cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
    qr.moveCenter(cp)
    self.move(qr.topLeft())
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for PtQt5 - thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

The other answers worked with a few deprecated warnings when using PySide2. So here is my version of the same function:

```
def center(self):
    screen = QtGui.QGuiApplication.screenAt(QtGui.QCursor().pos())
    fg = self.frameGeometry()
    fg.moveCenter(screen.geometry().center())
    self.move(fg.topLeft())
```

Comment: This works great with Qt6 since other answers used deprecated functions

Answer (score 1):

This is the update that works with **pyside6**:

```py
def center(self):
    frame_geo = self.frameGeometry()
    screen = self.window().windowHandle().screen()
    center_loc = screen.geometry().center()
    frame_geo.moveCenter(center_loc)
    self.move(frame_geo.topLeft())
```

It will move the window to the center of the screen where it is located.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.move(QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center().x() - self.frameGeometry().center().x() * 0.5, QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center().y() - self.frameGeometry().center().y() * 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me, so I had to come up with my own solution.

This works with PyQt5 and for multiple monitors.

For different window dimensions just play with the multipliers:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

main_window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
multiplier_x = 2
multiplier_y = 2
cursor_pos = QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().cursor().pos()
screen = QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().screenNumber(cursor_pos)
pos_x = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(screen).center().x()
pos_x -= main_window.frameGeometry().center().x() * multiplier_x
pos_y = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(screen).center().y()
pos_y -= main_window.frameGeometry().center().y() * multiplier_y
main_window.move(pos_x, pos_y)
```

Comment: I used it and my window went outside any of the monitors' views (:

Answer (score 0):

```
frameGeometry = self.frameGeometry()
windowFrameGeometry = self.window.frameGeometry()
x = int(frameGeometry.center().x()-windowFrameGeometry.center().x())
y = int(frameGeometry.center().y()-windowFrameGeometry.center().y())
self.window.move(x,y)
```