# PyQt5 Weird window position issue

Tags: python, python-3.4, pyqt5

The codes above, weirdly have an issue. I don't understand why but if I set `y` size of the window more than `923`, the window is not placed at the middle of the screen. It goes to the top-left corner of the screen.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QDesktopWidget,QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore

import sys

class cssden(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        self.mwidget = QMainWindow(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)


        #size
        self.setFixedSize(1100,923) # <--- set this 924 and more
        self.center # <-- function that set the window middle of the screen
        self.show()

    def center(self): # <-- center function
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow{background-color: rgb(30,30,30);border: 1px solid black}")

ex = cssden()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Why? Is this about the resolution of my screen which is 1920x1080? I just don't understand why the number is `923` and how to fix this.

**Edit**: It turns out PyQt center the window automatically, after `923` why it's going to left-top corner of the screen? Are there default numbers for each resolutions?

Comment: I notice that you're not actually calling `center()`.  Could that be the issue.

Comment: @BrendanAbel No, below `923` the window is center on center of the screen. See that `self.center`

Comment: @GLHF @BrendanAbel is right.  While the window may be getting centered, you are not actually calling the self.center() in the above code.  You're simply getting the reference.  You need the parens in `self.center()`. :-)

Comment: @jszakmeister but then why the window is on the middle of screen below `923` if I don't call it?

Comment: I commented out your center routine and the self.center line and it still centers the window.  It must be a default behavior, until you exceed some percentage of the screen.  Adding the parens fixes the problem.

Comment: @jszakmeister Well then I'm wondering why is that behaviour, why the number is 923

Comment: I don't know why... I don't know Qt well enough to say.  It may be due to a bug... you'd have to look at the Qt source to really find the answer.  But my guess would be that Qt is trying to take into account margins, room for scrollbars, and other such stuff and that's putting it beyond a limit and causes the behavior.  I suspect to get a real answer, you'd need to talk to the Qt guys.  In fact, I'd file a bug report, since the behavior seems off.

Comment: The answer will be: they needed a cutoff number/percentage/whatever and it ended up being this one.

Comment: BTW: changing `self.center` to `self.center()` inside your `__init__` does fix the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution from this answer: [PyQt4 center window on active screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20243637/pyqt4-center-window-on-active-screen)

```
def center(self):
    frameGm = self.frameGeometry()
    screen = QtGui.QApplication.desktop().screenNumber(QtGui.QApplication.desktop().cursor().pos())
    centerPoint = QtGui.QApplication.desktop().screenGeometry(screen).center()
    frameGm.moveCenter(centerPoint)
    self.move(frameGm.topLeft())
```

> This function is based on where the mouse point is located. It uses
>   the screenNumber function to determine which screen the mouse is
>   current active on. It then finds the screenGeometry of that monitor
>   and the center point of that screen. Using this method, you should be
>   able to place the window in the center of a screen even if monitor
>   resolutions are different.