# PyQt5 Unwanted fullscreen view when launching application on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyqt, pyqt5, ubuntu-20.04

I have an PyQt5 application that is opening in fullscreen mode when I don't want it too on Ubuntu 20.04. I have a large main window with a minimum size of 1830 x 900 and I've tried moving it in various ways but nothing seems to work. What I do notice is that the window initially opens in the upper left corner over the launcher and I think this causes it to go into fullscreen mode. I can't seem to move the window into a different start-up location. Any help with issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to control the start location, do some of these help? (Note updates for later versions of Qt) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20243637/pyqt4-center-window-on-active-screen

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't work. Any kind of use of move() hasn't been of any help, the window always first opens in the upper left corner. The window also has a fixed size of 1830 x 900.

Comment: Have you tried `setGeometry` to position the upper left corner? If you edit what you have tried into the question, it will avoiding people wasting time suggesting them.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].